# How can I make a IF ELSE statement in PHP from a response of JSON?

Tags: php, html, json, if-statement, echo

Guys I want to echo that when I get

- **as response 0**: 'YOU ARE NOT BANNED'
- **response 1**: 'YOU ARE BANNED'

info:
*I get the response in form of JSON

state : 0 OR 1

0 for not banned and 1 for banned*

This is how the problem looks like:

```
<?php if (strstr($characters['message']['state']) == 1) {
    echo "YOU ARE BANNED";
 } else if (strstr($characters['message']['state']) == 0) {
    echo "YOU ARE NOT BANNED";
 };
```

I always get `YOU ARE NOT BANNED` even if the response from JSON is `1`

I use the first  `<?php` because it is inside a HTML(which is inside a php file)...

Comment: *"because it is inside a HTML"* - What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: So I have a PHP file where I define my preprocess than outside the php I did write html and now I want in that html to do what I did write

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. What is the input, what is the content of `$characters`?

Comment: '$json = file_get_contents($api_uid); //put the contents of the file into a variable'
'$characters = json_decode($json, true);'

Comment: Lıke really I did write it is about a response from JSON so message -> state and the response of state is 0 OR 1 where 0 not banned and 1 is banned means...

Comment: `strstr()` needs 2 arguments. You're missing the argument with the string you're searching for.

Comment: @Barmar So I just want to check the output of ´$characters['message']['state']´ AND if it is '1' to echo banned and etc.... but I dont know how :'(

Comment: Then use `if ($characters['message']['state'] == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `strstr()`, just compare the variable directly. And if it's just a `1` or `0`, those can be treated as booleans, so you don't even need a comparison.

```
if ($characters['message']['state']) {
    echo "You are banned";
} else {
    echo "You are not banned";
}
```

Comment: Just a question and if it was if ($characters['message']) == 'succes') .... Would this work for a string tho?

Comment: Except you have an extra `)` before `==`.

Comment: Also, `$characters['message']` seems to be an array, so it should be `if ($characters['message']['state'] == 'success')`